# FastCGI or HTTP server for C++ daemon behind nginx proxy

Tags: c++, http, fastcgi

For high performance application accessible over web interface, would it make sense to implement/reuse some http server or go with fastcgi? I was convinced that fcgi would be correct choice, but I come across https://ef.gy/fastcgi-is-pointless and now I'm not so sure..

HTTP doesn't allow handling multiple sessions at one time, but that could be solved with spawning multiple deamon and let nginx act as balancer. But it would probably be *much* easier to test.

On the other hand, fcgi seems like having all necessary high-performance parts already in place (multiplexing requests in one process, therefore easier to implement cache, ...).

Does HTTP have *any* advantage over FastCGI aside from being easier to debug?

NOTE: Security is not so much of an issue since either fcgi or http will run behind nginx proxy.

Comment: Why not skip the NGINX server altogether and implement your solution using the Restbed framework?  Disclosure, I'm the author.  https://github.com/corvusoft/restbed

Comment: A like nginx for serving static content. To the restbed: While I must admit that it looks really interesting, I'm not so keen on the licensing terms.. I always liked more licences per-developer, not per-install site. But aside from that, it looks quite cool and will probably give it a try sometimes. One question. I expect that `Session::wait_for` can be used to pause current method execution and let other requests be processed. But it's possible to somehow wait for condition variable? Waiting time will sadly not be known in advance..

Comment: Correct wait_for will still allow other requests to proceed in a non-blocking fashion.  In regards to the condition variable question, I'm currently working on the following feature:   Session::wait_until( trigger, callback( session, future ) ).

Comment: hm, that would be cool. I could off-load heavy processing into other threads while keeping the "gui" one free for input/output.. out of curiosity, do you have ETA on that feature?

Comment: If you raise an issue via the tracker. I'll prioritise it for this weekend, end of next week at the latest; and keep you informed.

Comment: probably will do :) need to look it over again when I get home but at the moment it seems that the few missing things (didn't found anything for cookies) wouldn't be that hard to write myself..

Comment: Take a look at the following example. Let me know your thoughts. https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed/blob/master/example/wait_for_external_event/source/example.cpp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acting as HTTP server will force you to implement some things which is unrelated to your app's business logic. This includes but not limited to: keep-alive, chunked encodings, decoding forms data and many other little or big things. I'd prefer to stick with fastcgi since its requires less knowledge about transport-level protocol.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, making your C++ application a specialized Web server (e.g. with [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) library, or even [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)) would make it quite easy to debug. Both can be used in a session aware way and will deal with the nitty-gritty details (caching, chunked encoding, transport-compression, ...). I guess (but don't know) that their HTTP performance might be slightly lower (both libraries are probably not as optimized as *nginx* is rumored to be). And they probably are best suited with a few dozens (or perhaps hundreds) of simultaneously active users, not thousands of ones (but I don't know, and never used them with that much users...).

And perhaps you might have real user cases for that (it really depends what the application is actually doing, and if you have users running Linux or some other POSIX systems...)

BTW, if you know (or want to learn) Ocaml, you might even use [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/); if you know Scheme or some other Lisp, consider [HOP](http://hop.inria.fr/); if you are willing to learn a new language consider [OPA](http://opalang.org/) (or maybe [Haxe](http://haxe.org/)). All of these beasts enable you to *easily* mix server-side and browser-side computations.

Comment: libonion is linux only? seems like that from the link.. Other than that, it looks cool. Regarding the Wt, I don't know, I tried that and found out the whole web-like-gui-app concept doesn't suit me very well.. not saying that Wt is bad, it's just me..